# When filtering pandas dataframe latter column values are being dropped?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, rows

I'm trying to filter dataframe columns based on whether the subsc_type column value is 'Registered' or 'Casual'. The original data looks like;

```
    data.head()

end_statn   bike_nr    subsc_type    zip_code    birth_date    gender
23.0    B00468    Registered    '97217    1976.0    Male
23.0    B00554    Registered    '02215    1966.0    Male
```

I've not included all columns, but all columns to the left of and including 'subsc_type' maintain their values, however the following columns do not. The code I'm using and the data after this is;

```
    registered = data[data.subsc_type == 'Registered']
    casual = data[data.subsc_type == 'Casual']

    casual.head()

end_statn   bike_nr subsc_type  zip_code    birth_date  gender
47.0    B00368   Casual   NaN    NaN    NaN
40.0    B00358   Casual   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Any help would be amazing! Thanks!

Comment: from your sample data it is not possible to recreate the casual dataframe, include more data for  us to help you

Comment: Post a [mcve] .. preferably with the index showing, such that its clear the "before" and "after"data. Seems like you are doing everything fine, and that those values are `NaN` in the original data set, so thats why its showing `NaN` there (and not "dropping" or changing values are you suggested)

Comment: I was just searching through the data to find a Casual entry (there's not many of them) and realised I've massively overlooked the data. Casual user's don't need to include their zip code, birth date or gender, so the NaN values are from the original dataset. Thank-you for your help!